# Passing multiple variables of different types from dataframe to function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'selectionId': [8567238,7450487,12787737,9541421,10162696,7208966,8826166,7256678],

 'Price': [4.1,4.6,5.5,7.2,7.8,17.0,32.0,34.0],

 'Win_Percentage': [0.245870,0.212396,0.178922,0.145448,0.111974,0.078501,0.045027,0.011553],

  'Fit':[0.245870,0.212396,0.178922,0.145448,0.111974,0.078501,0.045027,0.011553],

   'size':[2.708701,2.373962,2.039223,1.704484,1.369744,1.035005,0.700266,0.365527]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['selectionId', 'Price', 'Win_Percentage','Fit','size'])
```

I also have the following function:

```
def test(marketId, selectionId):

    global place_order_Req

    place_order_Req = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"' + marketId + '","instructions":'\


'[{"selectionId":"' + str(
        selectionId) + '","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"1.9","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}'"""
print(place_order_Req)
"""
```

The marketId variable always has value `marketId = "1.156196315"`

I would like to pass the `selectionId` value in `df` to the function.

I would also like to pass the values of the size column to the function to change `"size":"1.9"` part of the function.

To summarise I would like the following to be returned from the function:

```
'{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"8567238","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"2.708701","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}\n    print(place_order_Req)\n    '
```

and for this to be done for each row of the dataframe.

To do this I have tried the following:

```
selectionId = df['selectionId']

size = df['size'].astype(str)

def test(marketId, selectionId, size):

    global place_order_Req, place_order_Req_list, place_order_Req_size_list

    place_order_Req_list = []

    place_order_Req_size_list = []

    for i in selectionId:
        place_order_Req = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"' + marketId + '","instructions":'\
                                                                                                                              '[{"selectionId":"' + str(
            i) + '","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"1","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}'
        """
    print(place_order_Req)
    """
        place_order_Req_list.append(place_order_Req)

    for j in place_order_Req_list:

        place_order_Req = place_order_Req[:208] + j + place_order_Req[:209]

        place_order_Req_size_list.append(place_order_Req)

    print(place_order_Req_size_list)
```

This changes the `selectionId` variable fine but when I try to change the `"1.9"` it does not work. It also returns itself twice for each input to the `place_order_Req_size_list` list.

I also think there must be a smarter way than using two loops.

This is the list that it returns:

```
['{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"8567238","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"1","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"', '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7450487","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"1","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{', '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"12787737","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"1","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{', '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"9541421","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"1","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{', '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"10162696","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"1","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{', '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7208966","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"1","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{', '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"8826166","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"1","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{', '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"1","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"1.156196315","instructions":[{"selectionId":"7256678","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":{']
```

Any help would be great, cheers.
Sandy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just apply a function to each row of your data frame. You can read the fields `'selectionId'` and `'size'` for each row and pass them on to your `place_order_Req` variable. Also, I'm not sure if you actually need to define/use `place_order_Req` as a global variable.

```
def test(x):    
    marketId = "1.156196315" #static value
    selectionId = x['selectionId']
    size = x['size']

#     global place_order_Req
    place_order_Req = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"' + marketId + '","instructions":' '[{"selectionId":"' + str(selectionId) + '","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT", "limitOrder":{"size": "'+ str(size) + '","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}'
    print(place_order_Req)

df.apply(test, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've now reviewed the code and it works with the following but I still think there must be a better method than using two loops:

```
size = df['size'].astype(str)
size = '"' + size + '"'

def test(marketId, selectionId, size):

    global place_order_Req, place_order_Req_list, place_order_Req_size_list

    place_order_Req_list = []

    place_order_Req_size_list = []

    for i in selectionId:
        place_order_Req = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"' + marketId + '","instructions":'\
                                                                                                                              '[{"selectionId":"' + str(
            i) + '","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"1","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}'
        """
    print(place_order_Req)
    """
        place_order_Req_list.append(place_order_Req)

    for j in size:

        place_order_Req = place_order_Req[:208] + j + place_order_Req[:209]

        place_order_Req_size_list.append(place_order_Req)

    print(place_order_Req_size_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply`:

```
def query(marketId, selectionId, size):

    global place_order_Req

    place_order_Req = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/placeOrders", "params": {"marketId":"' + marketId + '","instructions":'\
                      '[{"selectionId":"' + str(selectionId) + '","handicap":"0","side":"BACK","orderType":"LIMIT","limitOrder":{"size":"' \
                      + str(size) + '","price":"1.1","persistenceType":"LAPSE"}}],"customerRef":"test12121212121"}, "id": 1}'

    return place_order_Req

marketId = "1.156196315"
queries = df.apply(lambda x: query(marketId, x.selectionId, x.size), axis=1)

queries_list = queries.values.tolist() # list of your queries strings
```